# Performance Entity Framework Code First

Tags: performance, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a performance problem using code first and entity framework. I only want to read a simple mapping info which to up to 3 seconds.

```
// The enity
[Table("ResourceMappingEntity")]
    public class ResourceMappingEntity
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the testing number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The testing number.
        /// </value>
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string LocationNameOrIp { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string Resource { get; set; } //todo mb: noch nicht drin

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string App { get; set; } //todo mb: noch nicht drin

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the created at.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The created at.
        /// </value>
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    }

//the query
  using (var ctx = new OsmaTestingContextFactory().Create())
                {
                    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;


                    var two = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                    var dif = two - one;

                    IEnumerable<string> res = await ctx.ResourceMappingEntityStorage.AsNoTracking()
                                                .Where(
                                                    x => x.LocationNameOrIp == IPOrName)
                                                .Select(y => y.Resource)
                                                .ToListAsync();

                    var three = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                    var dif2 = three - two;

                    if (res.Count() != 1)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Can not find a specific resouce");
                    }

                    return res.First();
                }


// I also set IsUnicode to false....
```

Any ideas?

Hope for help or alternative solutions?! Should be ok in a few milliseconds like in SQL managment studio

Is there a good or standrad way to test the performance of ef?

Thx

Marcus

Comment: Does the query take place in a UnitTest?

Comment: Yes, in this example. But in my normal code it is slow, too.

Comment: And the time your writting about is dif2?

Comment: Yes, sorry.This should be the time for quering the data

Comment: How many rows are in the table? And why you use toListAsync() and then First()? You could get it faster, if you don't have to initialize a List.

Comment: Hi, there are only afew rows in it. Max 100 when it is finished. The using of listasync is copied from another service because I think I have a global problem. Using another solution like first direct or pure sql with select top 1 will show the same slow result

Comment: Did you try without the Select-call?

Comment: var res = ctx.ResourceMappingEntityStorage.AsNoTracking()
                                     .Where(x => x.LocationNameOrIp == IPOrName);

Comment: It is always slow. MAybe there is a problem of typecast, but me fields ar vachar(80) in datbase and string in c#

Comment: If you want to be sure, if it's a EF-issue, or maybe your Connection to the Database is that slow, you can try to use the Connection of your context and execute a SqlCommand directly.

Comment: Hi, it is also slow when using context.Database.SqlQuery .....

Comment: Context.Database.SqlQuery() is also a DbContext-Method. I'm talking about using context.Database.Connection, to create a SqlCommand and run this.

Comment: Ok, doing like this it is 600 ms.Think it is always to slow......

Comment: IF you mean it's still to slow, this is how the Overhead (Frameworks...) slow the perfomance down. In SSMS it's faster, because it's specialized in querying. Did you check, which Query EF has made?

Comment: Ok, from my point of view i think it is to slow and 600 ms for overhead..... ok.... Entit framework creates a similiar query to my own. Might be the data mapping the problem? cast types?